# Emmet 2.4.3 slows down Atom 1.4.5.0 massively

Tags: emmet

Thanks for looking into my situation.

My problem is that **emmet slows down atom** to the point where it renders it unusable. 
I`ve isolated the effect being caused by enabling emmet in the packages section in settings of Atom. It is only when I enable Emmet 2.4.3 that the lag appears. And man is it lagging.

**Pressing return calls for 4-5s of waiting. The same happens after pressing Tab**. Sometimes even the function of those two entries won`t be registered after the 5 seconds of waiting.

As soon as I disable the plug-in everything goes back to normal and I can even call out a standard boilerplate for HTML while emmet is disabled (which is kinda odd but hey..)

I have installed a few other plugins but for the purpose of this issue chasing drama, I disabled all of them in order to test each and every individually.

I even reinstalled atom but got to the same sluggish lagging experience as soon as I install and enable emmet, which is the first and only plugin I would install after the fresh installation of Atom.

This is fairly frustrating as I just started learning to how code in html and the lag turns my expirience into hell. 
Any information and suggestions are very, very welcome.

regards,
Mario

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if you open very large document. You could try [new plugin prototype](https://github.com/emmetio/atom-plugin) for Atom, or you can use VSCode editor.

Alternatively, try Sublime Text editor with upcoming [Emmet 2 plugin](https://github.com/emmetio/sublime-text-plugin)

Comment: Thank you for your input Sergey. 

I thought the same in the beginning since my playground file could be a messy code. So to find out if that was the case - a beefy file putting too much stress on my system , I just started a new blank html file, with closing all other tabs. Even without typing a single letter in the text editor in the new file the lag is still persistent in all scenarios (with pressing Tab or Return). 

My video course teacher (web development online course) uses Atom. Will I be "ok" following him using vscode. If it is virtually the same I probably would go for it.